# RFC Repository of programming RFC's with ability to direct-link sections or even lines?

Tags: hosting, rfc

Forgive me if this is the wrong place to ask this, I feel like the question is slightly off-topic even though it is also about programming.

I am inputting todo-tasks for my WebDAV-project into my issue tracker, as I read through the relevant RFC's, and it would be nice to be able to add a link in my issue text directly to the relevant text, instead of just a link to the RFC file with a section number in the issue text, and then I have to use the find function to find it.

For instance, a link like this:

- http://ieft.org/rfc2518.txt#1000 <-- line 1000
- http://ieft.org/rfc2518.txt#9.8.3 <-- section 9.8.3

Neither of these two works, since they just post the full text files, so my question is this: Does anyone know of hosted versions of the RFC documents that contains such links?

Comment: Or perhaps I should just make such a hosted site myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a better solution would to be use a richer language for expressing links to the text-only version. It exists! [RFC 5147: URI Fragment Identifiers for the text/plain Media Type](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5147.txt). For instance:

- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2518.txt#line=1000

It has a (very limited) [implementation](http://www.bortzmeyer.org/files/TextFrag.py) and a (better?) one in the browser Amaya.

For the HTML (unofficial) versions, there is the possibiity you request at the excellent [tools.ietf.org](http://tools.ietf.org/). For instance:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2518#section-9.8

Comment: Nice, that link to tools.ietf.org was exactly what I needed, to link directly to a line is just a bonus, but a link to the relevant section is more than good enough!