# How do I make a table of contents in a plain text document interactive using a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, browser, greasemonkey, plaintext, tableofcontents

I came across a fairly recent [RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5147.txt) on "URI Fragment Identifiers for the text/plain Media Type". I ran a few tests on the URL itself in Chrome and IE to no avail. For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt#line=50

Should work similar to:

https://stackoverflow.com/about#footer

How do I write a Greasemonkey script to do the following:

- Map the table of contents to the line it references and add a hyperlink to each table of contents listing which maps to the respective line number?

Comment: It would be helpful to show what you tested and what you expected, or any other hints to give someone a leg up on researching this.

Comment: @mjhm I've added examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing is the [addrable](https://github.com/mhausenblas/addrable) project. It is targeting the `text/csv` MIME type, and has jQuery and NodeJS implementations. Outside of the browser landscape, [Canonical Fragment Identifiers](http://epub.anfengde.com/tag/epub-cfi/) for ePub would be a bridge between plain text and markup.

**References**

- [addrable-core.js](https://github.com/mhausenblas/addrable/blob/master/addrable-core.js)
- [readium-cfi.js](https://github.com/readium/readium-cfi-js)
- [Chromium Issue 77024: RFC 5147 plain text position fragments](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=77024)
- [Microsoft Connect Issue 652715: RFC 5147 Plain Text Positions Given as URI Fragment](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/652715/rfc-5147-plain-text-line-positions-given-as-uri-fragment)
- [W3C Existing Technologies Survey: Existing URI Fragment Schemes](http://www.w3.org/2008/WebVideo/Fragments/wiki/Existing_Technologies_Survey)
- [Aggregating Media Fragments in Collaborative Mashups(pdf)](http://www.w3.org/2013/04/odw/ODW13-CrossLinks-Pres.pdf)
- [RFC Repository of programming RFC's with ability to direct-link sections or even lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819935/1113772)